Assigning roles with additional attributes Keycloak
Imagine I have a role “Mayor”. Now I want to assign this role to my users mentioning which city this user is its mayor. For example:

user A is the mayor of city C1

user B is the mayor of city C2.


I tried handling this with role attributes, but role attributes cannot be changed in assigning roles to users. So it was impossible. Now I want a solution which can handle adding additional information or additional attributes in assigning roles to users
Does anyone have any idea how can I handle this in Keycloak?
